# Can a single drive RAID 0 be converted to a standard drive?

Tags: raid, raid-0

A while back I set up a **single drive** in RAID 0 on a RAID card. I now want to switch my card to HBA mode. Will my RAID 0 drive read as a standard drive or will the data be lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the subject, the RAID 0 software has written its header on the
disk, so it is not in the format of a simple disk.

I suggest taking a backup of your data before switching to HBA mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this exact scenario before (a single drive RAID 0 doesn't make sense to me), but I would expect since the partition table and drive headers need to be re-written the data would be lost.